# execute some function on arriving a new observer in Angular BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I would like to execute some function when a new observer arrives for a BehaviorSubject in Angular.

```
export class MyClass {
  public bs: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  private observerCount: number = 0;

    :

  private someFunction() {
    this.observerCount++;
  }
    
  private checkNewObservers() {      
    setInterval( () => {
      for (const o of this.bs.observers) {
        if (...) { // o is a new observer
          someFunction(); // I would like to do this immediately after a new observer arrives.
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Probably I can do it with the code like above. But it will be delayed until `someFunction` is executed. I would like execute `someFunction` immediately after a new observer arrives.

How can I do this?

Comment: why you don't subscribe it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of repetedly checking for new observers, you can achieve what you are looking for by extending `BehaviorSubject` to accept a callback to execute when an observer is added, as demonstrated below:

**BehaviorSubject With Notifier**

```
class BehaviorSubjectWithNotifier<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T>{
  public notifier: Function;

  constructor(value: T, notifier: Function) {
    super(value);
    this.notifier = notifier;
  }

  _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
    this.notifier()
    return super._subscribe(subscriber);
  }
}
```

**Usage Example:**

```
const x = new BehaviorSubjectWithNotifier(VALUE, () => console.log("observer added"));

x.subscribe() // new obsever has been added
x.subscribe() // new obsever has been added
x.subscribe() // new obsever has been added
```

**Going ever further**

instead of using callback function use `Subject` to keeps track of current observers number, so that you can get notified as a new observer is added, as following:

```
class BehaviorSubjectWithNotifier<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T>{
  public count$ = new Subject<number>();

  _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
    this.count$.next(this.observers.length); // push current observers number
    return super._subscribe(subscriber);
  }

  unsubscribe(){
    this.count$.unsubscribe();
    super.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

**Usage Example:**

```
const subject = new BehaviorSubjectWithNotifier(VALUE);

subject.count$.subscribe(count => {
  // run some code
})
```

Comment: This is the answer I was going to suggest.